# How to Show Most Recent Article in Rails app in another view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails Blog app I have my welcome controller and view `index.html.erb`. And I have my articles controller and views `index.html.erb` and `show.html.erb`.

My articles view has two views, one for listing articles `index.html.erb`, and the other for showing articles `show.html.erb`. When listing articles in my articles view everything works perfectly. But my goal is to list the most recent article in a popup modal in my welcome view `index.html.erb`.

Below is the code for listing articles in the articles view

```
<% @articles.reverse.each do |article| %>
                <div class="w3-quarter">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 300px; min-height: 300px;">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                          <h3><%= article.title %></h3>
                          <p class="w3-opacity"><%= article.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>  |  Comments <span class="label label-primary"><%= article.comments.count %></span> </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <p><%= article.text.first(250) %> ...</p>
                          <%= link_to 'Read More', article_path(article), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% end %>
```

And below is the code for listing the most recent article in my welcome view

```
<!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <h2><%= @article.title %></h2>
                  <p class="w3-opacity">Posted on <%= @article.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></p>
                  <hr>
                  <p><%= @article.text.first(500) %></p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

I get the following error from my welcome `index.html.erb`:

`` undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass ``

Any ideas?

Comment: The @article variable is nil. Are you assigning it to something?

Comment: Show us the `welcome_controller` code

Comment: I actually don’t have anything assigned to it. How would I go about storing my latest article in `@article`?  In my articles/index.html.erb it stores an article in `article` using a for loop. But I don’t want to loop through every article, I just want the most recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are not setting `@article` in you `welcome_controller`

Try something this

```
class WeclomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @artice = Article.order(created_at: :desc).first
  end

end
```

Comment: @m.simonborg `first` will also limit the collection to only first record
`Article.order(created_at: :desc).first` and `Article.order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)` will fire the same query to database

Comment: You were right right, I didn't set @article in my welcome_controller. Once I put in `@artice = Article.order(created_at: :desc).first`, it worked perfectly!

Comment: I do have a question, if I set @article in my application_controller, will that variable become accessible throughout the entire application?

Comment: @NimishGupta you're right, i already deleted the comment when i realized the mistake

Comment: @micheal yes it will be available through the entire application. But you have to make sure you don't set it any other controller, otherwise it will.get override